# how to output a double to 2 decmial places in a string?

Tags: java, formatting, decimal

This program makes temperature conversions using an itemListener

outputValue is a protected double

outputString is also protected

output is a is a JTextField

and output type is a protected char

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    inputValue =  Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());

    //the input value is converted to the outputValue based on the outputType

    outputString = String.valueOf(outputValue);            //set output value to string
    outputString = String.format(" %0.2f", outputValue);   //format to .00

    output.setText( outputString + (char) 0x00B0 + outputType);}
```

When I run the program I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: 0.2f,
```

with a long list of (unknown sources).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use format string `%.2f`:

```
String.format(" %.2f", outputValue);
```

Comment: Any idea what caused the exception? The name of the exception says there's a missing format width, yet the OP had `%0.2f` in which 2 is the width, right?

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer from Glenn Lane answers the question, how to do this correctly.

As for why the exception occurred, a careful search of the [Formatter javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) reveals this about the `0` flag:

> Requires the output to be padded with leading zeros **to
>   the minimum field width** following any sign or radix indicator except
>   when converting NaN or infinity. If the **width is not provided**, then a
>   MissingFormatWidthException will be thrown.

So, `%0.2f` is saying that the number should be padded with zeroes to  `n` places before the decimal (and 2 digits should be shown after the decimal). But `n` is left unspecified.

That's why `%0.2f` throws a `MissingFormatWidthException`, and `%.2f` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like `" %03.2f"`, the first 0 is just a flag to pad the number with leading zeros. It must be followed by a width specification.

Comment: It seems in Java8 if you don't add the width specification you will get the java error java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: %0.2f
  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkNumeric(Formatter.java:3022)
....

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
String outputType = " celsius";
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
output.setText( format.format(Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()))+ outputType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the format you have chosen appears to be wrong the correct one would be

```
outputString = String.format(" %.2f", outputValue);
```